# how to change aspx with javascript functions from aspx.cs?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I am working on an asp.net web app project, and I have a button which is using javascript for drop down menu:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnPlant1" runat="server" Width="160px" BackColor="Transparent"
                                Height="40px" CssClass="buttonStyle" onmouseover="MM_showMenu(window.langT,0,40,null,'BtnPlant1');" 
              onmouseout=MM_startTimeout();/>
```

And I have a dropdown list for change drop down menus.

For example when `dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text == "langE"` I want to change `onmouseover` to this:

```
onmouseover="MM_showMenu(window.langE,0,40,null,'BtnPlant1');"
//                                  ^-- (langE, not langT)
```

How can I do this? Any idea? Thanks...

Comment: Change window.langT to this.selectedOptions[0].innerText

Answer (score 0):

You should have jquery... so try something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnPlant1" runat="server" Width="160px" BackColor="Transparent"
                                Height="40px" CssClass="buttonStyle" onmouseover="showMenu()" 
              onmouseout=MM_startTimeout();/>
```

javascript:

```
function showMenu() {
       if($('.dropdownlist').val() == "langE")
         MM_showMenu(window.langE,0,40,null,'BtnPlant1');
       else
         MM_showMenu(window.langT,0,40,null,'BtnPlant1');
}

$('.dropdownlist').change(function() {
  showMenu();  
}
```

Not testet!....

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
function showMenu() {
           if($("#ddlistid option:selected").text() == "langE")
               MM_showMenu(window.langE,0,40,null,'BtnPlant1');
           else
                MM_showMenu(window.langT,0,40,null,'BtnPlant1');
         }
```